# MySQL Subquery as Criteria

Tags: mysql

I have a problem regarding a query where i want to only display data where its count of a subquery must be greater than 0.

I have this sql query:

```
SELECT
  t.id           AS t__id,
  t.state_code   AS t__state_code,
  t.number       AS t__number,
  t.meta         AS t__meta,
  t.date_created AS t__date_created,
  (SELECT
     COUNT(t2.id)   AS t2__0
   FROM tbl_messages t2
     LEFT JOIN tbl_services t3
       ON t2.service_id = t3.id
   WHERE (t2.inbound_time BETWEEN "2011-01-31 16:00:00"
          AND "2011-02-28 15:59:59"
          AND t2.subscriber = t.number
          AND t3.pool_id = 48)) AS t__0
FROM tbl_subscribers t
WHERE (TRUE)
ORDER BY t__0 DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

i want to display only the data where t__0 > 0... how do i apply it in this query?

i tried this query but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT
  t.id           AS t__id,
  t.state_code   AS t__state_code,
  t.number       AS t__number,
  t.meta         AS t__meta,
  t.date_created AS t__date_created,
  (SELECT
     COUNT(t2.id)   AS t2__0
   FROM tbl_messages t2
     LEFT JOIN tbl_services t3
       ON t2.service_id = t3.id
   WHERE (t2.inbound_time BETWEEN "2011-01-31 16:00:00"
          AND "2011-02-28 15:59:59"
          AND t2.subscriber = t.number
          AND t3.pool_id = 48)) AS t__0
FROM tbl_subscribers t
WHERE (t__0 > 0)
ORDER BY t__0 DESC
LIMIT 100
```

;

it returns an error:

```
Query : SELECT    t.id           AS t__id,    t.state_code   AS t__state_code,    t.number       AS t__number,    t.meta         AS t__m...
Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'having t__0 > 0
LIMIT 100' at line 19
Execution Time : 00:00:00:000
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
Total Time     : 00:00:00:000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT
  t.id           AS t__id,
  t.state_code   AS t__state_code,
  t.number       AS t__number,
  t.meta         AS t__meta,
  t.date_created AS t__date_created,
  COUNT(t2.id)   AS t__0
FROM tbl_subscribers t
JOIN tbl_messages t2 ON t2.subscriber = t.number 
LEFT JOIN tbl_services t3 ON t2.service_id = t3.id 
WHERE t2.inbound_time BETWEEN "2011-01-31 16:00:00"
        AND "2011-02-28 15:59:59" 
        AND t3.pool_id = 48
GROUP BY t.id, t.state_code, t.number, t.meta, t.date_created 
HAVING COUNT(t2.id) > 0
ORDER BY t__0 DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: this solves the problem. but if ever i come across a scenario where i have to use the result of a subquery as basis for a condition in the criteria of the main query, how to do it?

Comment: @darkcolonist: Commented on the wrong Q before.  Based off the error message you're seeing, it looks like MySQL may be complaining about your t__0 not using a HAVING clause instead of a WHERE clause due to the aggregate function that determines what t__0 is. As you might notice in my answer, the HAVING clause comes after WHERE and GROUP BY clauses. See the ordering here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html